# Как посмотреть вопросы и ответы с удаленного аккаунта?

Tags: поддержка, поиск, удаление-профиля

Есть ли возможность посмотреть ответы с удаленного аккаунта?
Для примера, у меня раньше был аккаунт с таким же ником как и сейчас, который после удаления стал `user341547`, где-то можно увидеть список ответов с него?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Непосредственно в интерфейсе сайта такого нет для обычных пользователей (но есть для модераторов). Однако для поиска можно использовать запрос, [описанный на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284625/339911).

Результат под запрошенного user341547 юзера [здесь](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/346626?Name=user341547).

У меня было предложение сделать поиск в строке поиска в шапке сайта (через `user:id`) доступным и для удалённых пользователей: [Allow to search by user id when user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322802/339911)

Comment: Related: https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/112469/get-all-posts-by-deleted-user